# Increasing Space between Abbreviation and Full text in Acronym List

Tags: spacing, acronyms, acro

I am inserting some acronyms in a two-column scientific paper. Few of my abbreviations are large and are overlapping with their definitions. I am using acro package. Is there any way to increase the space between abbreviation and its definition so they do not overlap?

```
`\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{acro}
\include{Nomenclature}
\DeclareAcronym{bcdla}{
 short = BCDLA ,
 long  = Branch Current Decomposition method for Losses Allocation ,
 }
 \DeclareAcronym{nlaf}{
short = NLAFs ,
long  = Neutral Losses Allocation Factors ,
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms[sort=true]
\section{Introduction}
This is a \ac{bcdla} approach, utilizing \ac{nlaf}.
\end{document}`
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @samcarter As can be seen, BCDLA and NLAFs abbreviation overlaps their definitions. The question is how to increase the space between them.

Answer (score 2):

IEEE style redefines the `description` environment, which causes this problem. To temporarily change this behaviour you can use the following trick found in the IEEE user guide:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{acro}
%\include{Nomenclature}
\DeclareAcronym{bcdla}{
 short = BCDLA ,
 long  = Branch Current Decomposition method for Losses Allocation ,
 }
 \DeclareAcronym{nlaf}{
short = NLAFs ,
long  = Neutral Losses Allocation Factors ,
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\IEEEiedlistdecl}{\IEEEsetlabelwidth{SONET}}
\printacronyms[sort=true]
\renewcommand{\IEEEiedlistdecl}{\relax}% reset back

\section{Introduction}
This is a \ac{bcdla} approach, utilizing \ac{nlaf}.
\end{document}
```

[image]